# Problema al Ejecutar SP en MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedure

Tengo el siguiente problema. Tengo varios SP creados que llamo desde PHP para realizar cierta funcion. Todos me han funcionado correctamente, menos uno. Y ni idea del porque.

Este es el Erroe que me retorna al ejecutar el SP

> stdClass Object ( [estado] => 0 [mensaje] => ERROR 1045 (28000):
>   Access denied for user 'usuario'@'localhost' (using password: YES) )

Esto es del SP que tengo en error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y esto es de otro SP que funciona perfectamente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el codigo del SP

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `sp_agregar_nuevo_libro_usuario`(
    IN i_nombre TEXT,
    IN i_autor TEXT,
    IN i_slug TEXT,
    IN i_imagen_frontal TEXT,
    IN i_imagen_lateral TEXT,
    IN i_imagen_trasera TEXT,
    IN i_usuario_id INT,
    IN i_subcategoria_id INT,
    IN i_ip VARCHAR(255),
    OUT o_estado BOOLEAN,
    OUT o_mensaje TEXT
)
BEGIN

    DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
        BEGIN
            GET DIAGNOSTICS CONDITION 1 @sqlstate = RETURNED_SQLSTATE, 
            @errno = MYSQL_ERRNO, @text = MESSAGE_TEXT;
            SET o_mensaje  = CONCAT('ERROR ', @errno, ' (', @sqlstate, '): ', @text);
            SET o_estado = FALSE;
            ROLLBACK;
        END;

    START TRANSACTION;

    INSERT INTO libros(id, nombre, autor, slug, imagen_frontal, imagen_lateral, imagen_trasera, usuarios_id, subcategorias_id, estados_sistema_id, seg_created, seg_last_updated)
    VALUES(NULL, LOWER(i_nombre), LOWER(i_autor), LOWER(i_slug), i_imagen_frontal, i_imagen_lateral, i_imagen_trasera, i_usuario_id, i_subcategoria_id, (SELECT id FROM estados_sistema WHERE estado = 'Libro Disponible'), NOW(), NOW());

    INSERT INTO control_actividad_usuarios(id, accion, hora, ip, usuarios_id, seg_created, seg_last_updated)
    VALUES(NULL, 'Agregar Nuevo Libro', NOW(), i_ip, i_usuario_id, NOW(),NOW());

    COMMIT;

    SET o_mensaje = 'Libro Agregado Exitosamente';
    SET o_estado = TRUE;

END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Prueba asignando el `DEFINER` a nivel de la sintaxis y no desde el asistente de este modo:

```
CREATE DEFINER = 'tusuario'@'localhost' PROCEDURE `sp_agregar_nuevo_libro_usuario`(
```

Posterior a la línea anterior, escribe lo siguiente:

```
SQL SECURITY INVOKER
```

**Aclaraciones**

- `DEFINER` Indica la cuenta a la cual estará asociada incluyendo sus privilegios la creación de dicho procedimiento almacenado
- `SQL SECURITY INVOKER` Al tiempo llamará y ejecutará al PA, valiéndose de los permisos del usuario que lo invoca

**Referencias**

- [Sintaxis de procedimientos almacenados](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-procedure.html)

Comment: Hola, yo no lo coloco desde el asistente. Se coloca solo al ejecutar esa Query. Pero probare.

Comment: Nada, sigue apareciendo lo mismo. Todos los SP los he creado de la misma manera y este ha sido el unico dando error.